# Set ttl and namespace using Memcached in Zend Framework 2

Tags: memcached, zend-framework2, installation, ttl

As far as I can figure this seems to be the way to set up Memcached and set the TTL and Namespace but they have no effect in the cache. The key is not prefixed with a namespace and the expire is infinite.

```
    $MemcachedOptions = new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedOptions();
    $MemcachedResourceManager = new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedResourceManager(1, new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memcached());
    $MemcachedResourceManager->addServer(1, array('localhost', 11211));
    $MemcachedOptions->setResourceManager($MemcachedResourceManager);

    $MemcachedOptions->setNamespace('FooBar_');
    $MemcachedOptions->setTtl(10);

    $cache = $MemcachedOptions->getResourceManager()->getResource(1);
    $cache->set('foobar_key','I am in cache');
```

Does anyone have any tips, clues? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `MemcachedResourceManager` works different as you trying to use it.

You should initialize it like the following:

```
// init a memcached resource manager with one native memcached resource
// using resource id "1"
$MemcachedResourceManager = new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedResourceManager();
$MemcachedResourceManager->addServer('1', array('localhost', 11211));

// init a memcached storage adapter
// using the native memcached resource of id "1"
// configure it with a ttl and a namespace
$cache = \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::adapterFactory('memcached', array(
    'resource_manager' => $MemcachedResourceManager,
    'resource_id'      => '1',
    'namespace'        => 'FooBar_',
    'ttl'              => 10,
));

// or
$memcachedAdapterOptions = new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedOptions(array(
    'resource_manager' => $MemcachedResourceManager,
    'resource_id'      => '1',
    'namespace'        => 'FooBar_',
    'ttl'              => 10,
));
$cache = new \Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memcached($memcachedAdapterOptions);
```

How does the classes work together:

The most important class is `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memcached` it is a wrapper for a native instance of `Memcached` used in a context of `Zend\Cache\StorageInterface`.

This storage adapter has a number of options defined as `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedOptions`.

Because cache storage adapters in ZF2 are designed to handle one type of items to store you need different instances of `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memcached` for different type of items. But you don't wont to use different connections to a memcached (different instance of the native `Memcached` class) server - this is were `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedResourceManager` comes to play.

The `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\MemcachedResourceManager` handles native instances of `Memcached` which will be used by `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memcached`.

Comment: Excellent! That works (changed namesapce to namespace). Thank you for the two ways which helps my understanding.

Comment: Trying to get my head around "different instances of ..\Memcached for different type of items". What are "items" in this context and why would you want another instance of Memcached? The factory above will always use the same instance (unless you tell it otherwise)...no?

Comment: ``different instances of ..\Memcached for different type of items``: One type of item can be users and another type can be products. Each of them  would like to have a different ttl/namespace etc. configured. If you don't like to change the configuration before storing or reading an item you need different instances. PS: ``Zend\Cache\StorageFactory`` doesn't share instances - it creates a new instance on every call.